# Keep my classes and methods as small as possible?

Tags: code-quality, coding-style

A few days ago, I was talking to a Software Engineering PhD candidate and at some point she said to me:

> Keep your classes and methods as small as possible

And I wonder if this is always a good practice.

I mean for example, is it worthy to have a class with only 2 attibutes in it? For instance, In  some methods I need pairs of integers to work with. Should i write a "PairOfIntgers" class?

Could this way of thinking "break" the code in too many pieces?

Comment: That should be `"As small as possible, but no smaller."`

Comment: "I mean for example, is it worthy to have a class with only 2 attibutes in it?" - It can be, search for "Primitive Obsession" (e. g. http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/PrimitiveObsession.html)

Comment: I think the source of confusion is the word "possible". The principle becomes ridiculous if "possible" is referring only to the code, because the smallest possible class that does anything useful has only one method (and in some cases zero). The candidate very likely meant to take into account cohesion and coupling.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a grain of truth in that advice, but IMHO it is not very well expressed, thus easy to misunderstand and/or to take to a stupid extreme. At any rate, this should be a rule of thumb, rather than hard law. And you should always imply in such rules the clause *"within reasonable limits"*, or *"but don't forget to use your common sense"* :-)

The grain of truth is that **in practice, classes and methods always tend to grow by nature, not shrink**. A bug fix here, a little feature extension there, handling a special case over there... and voila, your once neat and small class starts to bloat. Over time, your code almost inevitably tends to become a monstrous mess of spaghetti - unless you actively fight this tendency via [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). Refactoring almost always produces many smaller classes / methods from a few big ones. But of course, there is a sensible limit to miniaturizing. **The point of refactoring is not to have smaller classes and methods per se, but to make your code cleaner, easier to understand and maintain**. At a certain point, making your methods / classes smaller starts to decrease readability, rather than increasing it. Aim towards that optimum. It is a blurry and moving target area, so you don't need to hit it spot on. Just [improve the code a little whenever you notice some problem with it](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1235624&seqNum=6).

Comment: definitely a rule to not follow blindly, too many tiny classes is so much worse than a few larger classes most of the time.

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is: if you can't see a whole method implementation on the screen at once, refactor.

Comment: @DanRay, yeah, I used to have the same rule, until I read [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). It was quite a shock, but gradually caused my optimum to go down to around 10 lines.

Comment: @DanRay: I think that is very artificial and changes depending on screen and font size...

Comment: @c_maker: Absolutely. Like I say, it's a rule of thumb. I've broken it plenty of times when I had good reason to. I guess the point is, having that rule forces me to actually think about the length of my methods.

Comment: @DanRay: It is not about size, it's about how you use it ;)

Comment: Back in the Dark Ages, the guideline was "one printer page".  The key insight is that comprehension drops dramatically the moment the programmer has to "turn a page", whether that means turning a physical printed page, scrolling a file, turning his head to the next listing or monitor, or whatever.  Read Weinberg's "Psychology of Computer Programming".

Comment: IMO *Clean Code* is horrible in its extremity towards small methods. The problem is that when methods are made smaller, there will be more of them. Of course too long methods are too long, but Bob Martin seems to prefer 10 1-line methods over 1 10-line one (thus the effectively same code taking about 5x as much screen space). Maybe it's meant to be some sort of educational trick, I can't believe someone actually thinks the code in that book is any good.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka, I do, although I don't take it to the extreme. My personal sweet spot is about 3 to 10 lines, but I do occasionally write single-line, as well as 30-line methods. If you are really worried about your code taking up too much space, you can format 1-line methods to a single line.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka - The main benefit of short methods is that they can do exactly one thing. This makes them very easy to read and test. Since targeting my methods to be smaller, I have found myself to be more productive, and I am spending less time fixing bugs.

Comment: @David Harkness: Yes, that's the advantage of short methods. But the advocates often forget to mention that it's a trade-off. More methods = more code to read, more potential points of failure and so on. Typically people make way too long methods so the advice towards shorter methods is generally good, but there are not many things that should be taken to the extreme (and Clean Code *does* take the smallness of methods to the extreme).

Comment: @JoonasPulakka - Let's just say I've never read a method and thought, "I wish this method did more." By shortening methods you can write very descriptive method names that can often eliminate the need to read the method body entirely. I found the advice in *Clean Code* to be very sensible. We'll just have to agree to disagree. :)

Comment: @JoonasPulakka I think the thing to focus on is not number-of-lines-of-code or number-of-methods, but readability and simplicity. "Clean Code" was a eureka for me and changed the way I write code. I want code to read as easily as English. When I read the code and it instantly makes sense, that is fantastic code. I don't want to have to think hard. With most code, I am forced to think and deduce. I have to read everything. Go through the sub-calls and sub-data-structures. If I see 10 dense lines with multiple steps and the purpose doesn't jump right out at me, it needs a well-named sub-method.

Answer (score 11):

The more important issue to stress here is **creating good abstractions**. **Small classes** that are loosely coupled and have high cohesion **are the product of good abstractions**.

Sometimes it makes perfect sense to encapsulate two integers in a class. Especially if you want to have methods 'attached' to this class to also encapsulate how one can manipulate these attributes and to make sure you protect them from other parts of the program changing them.

Another positive to create a class in this case is that the class can evolve a lot better/nicer than let's say a lower level data structure like a Map or List can.

Third, a good abstraction can improve readability a great deal. Classes that adhere to SRP are usually a lot easier to understand by a human than classes that do not.

And just as a final note... no matter how good of a student you are... to understand OOP and good abstractions and when to use them, you need experience. You need to write bad code and go through the pain to maintain it. You need to see others write good code to build up your knowledge about what is 'good' and what will be a problem down the line... So do not beat yourself up if you just do not get it right away.

Comment: Standard example of a _good_ class that has only two attributes: A class for complex numbers. Only needs `real_part` and `imaginary_part` but it's such an important abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

[The God Object anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) is what she was probably alluding to.  I do tend to think that if I have an "and" in my class description, I should have two classes.  If I have more than ten lines of code in a method/function, then I should break it up.  As the pirate code, those are more guidelines than rules.

Answer (score 2):

In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. Usually you are doing more than one thing if your class gets too big.
In your case the class is just a data class which holds data which is totaly ok. You shouldn't name the class PairOfInteger. What does the integers describe?
Depending on your scenario a Tuple (like in C#) might be sufficient, too.
And you may want to think about a strut instead of a class.

Try to hold you classes small. And methods even smaller. Maybe 10 Lines?!?
Currently I'm trying to use flow design and event based components which seems to help to hold classes small. First I was worried to get to many classes but it really works!!!
[http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126122649/http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx)
[http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/20/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-ii-translation.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118181648/http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/20/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-ii-translation.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler.** That's the rule I try to go by. Sometimes, it actually makes sense for a class to do what strictly speaking amounts to more than one thing, *if those things are related on some common theme*. Look at .NET; there are tons of classes that implement a large number of interfaces, each with its own list of required members. A method might end up needing to become somewhat long if it does something complex with a number of intermediate steps which are all interconnected and thus don't lend themselves very well to further refactoring. (Refactoring to keep methods short should ultimately be about readability and maintainability; if the long method is more readable and/or maintainable than a short one, all else equal, I will take the long one any day.)

To only "make classes and methods as small as possible" is, in my opinion, misguided. The real challenge is, as @c_maker points out, to provide good abstractions. Your example of grouping two numbers together is great, for example, if you are working on an implementation of complex numbers arithmetic, or if on a Unix system you need to refer to a user/group context. It makes very little sense if the numbers represent, say, an invoice ID and a product ID to be added to that invoice.

Answer (score 0):

That is OK advice, but it needs to be implemented somewhat intelligently.  Definitely don't follow it blindly.

When I look at my code I know if a method is too big. If it is doing too much, and would be too hard to read, then it is refactor time.

Here's a good example: you have a loop, and you have maybe 60 lines of code in that method.  In that case, it is probably time to refactor because you are likely doing too much in that method.

But, it isn't a hard and fast rule.  It's only something you get to learn by doing.  And, other developers you are working with my not always agree and may call you out in a code review or whatever.

Comment: Never make methods smaller rather follow SRP and it will automatically do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Uncle Bob says you should refactor/split/extract your methods **until it is impossible to make them smaller**. This usually ends in having several methods with 3 or 4 lines each. When you get too many methods, you have to make more classes.

If you try to follow SRP and one level of abstraction per method, these rules serve you well. At least they serve me well. Aiming for "as small as possible" gives me reasonable small methods, as I usually fall short the aim.

And it's always easier to understand smaller classes. Go ahead, read "Clean Code"

Answer (score 0):

Use common sense. The cost of reading and maintaining code is a function of function size and overhead. One huge function is more expensive than two very large functions plus the overhead of calling them. One very large function is more expensive than the cost of two large functions and the cost of calling them. But at some point splitting a function in two increases the cost, so don’t make your functions smaller at that point. And there is some range where you are close enough to the optimal size that you do what you personally prefer.

There is a situation where you will have quite small functions: When you use a function to abstract something away. For example whether a person receives a pension might be stored in a database. But as the caller, I don’t care which field in which database needs which value to identify if someone gets a pension. I want to write person.receivesPension. I don’t care if that function takes one line or 100 lines, but whatever the size you write one function. (In the case of 100 lines I wonder why this is so complicated, and you might have some private functions to help).

And don’t trust uncles even if they bring presents.